# @SerializedName not working with Proguard

Tags: android, gson, proguard

On `minifyEnabled true` on a project with Proguard the `ApiError` class is not parsed correctly while using Gson.

```
data class ApiResponse<D>(
    @SerializedName("status") @Expose val status: String,
    @SerializedName("data") @Expose val data: D?,
    @SerializedName("error") @Expose val error: ApiError?
)

data class ApiError(
    @SerializedName("code") @Expose val code: Int,
    @SerializedName("message") @Expose val msg: String,
    @SerializedName("title") @Expose val title: String?
)
```

The following code gives an `ApiResponse` object where `ApiError` is not properly parsed.

```
val collectionType = object : TypeToken<ApiResponse<User>?>() {}.type
                        val gson = GsonBuilder()
                        val errorBody: ApiResponse<T> = gson.create().fromJson(stringObj, collectionType)
```

Adding `@Keep` on `ApiError` solves the issue but shouldn't `@SerializedName` do the same?
Interestingly every field of `ApiResponse` is parsed properly.
We have the same proguard rules as [this one](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)

Comment: You should keep data classes in your proguard rules

Comment: @Rolud why any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your models still being obfuscated use annotation @SerializedName("name_of_json_key"). It will let gson know the real name of the field.

`-keepattributes *Annotation*`  in your proguard-rules.pro file.
that will  keep your annotations from obfuscation

Comment: Thats exactly the question. Inspite of @SerializedName("name_of_json_key") and -keepattributes *Annotation*, the variables are obfuscated.